# Dynamically creating objects with class property

Tags: javascript

I am creating a form where the user can dynamically add rows. Everything works fine except one thing: I cannot add class to certain input element created by the user:

This is how I add rows:

```
function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            break;
                    case "checkbox":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                            break;
                    case "select-one":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                            break;
                }
            }
        }
```

(Courtesy of [this site](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/))

Form:

```
<TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1" class="plantable">
            <TR>
                <TH></TH>
                <TH>From</TH>
                <TH>To</TH>
                <TH>When</TH>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
                <TD><INPUT type="text" name="from[]"/></TD>
                <TD><INPUT type="text" name="to[]"/></TD>
                <TD><INPUT type="text" name="when[]" class="datepicker"/></TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>

        <br/>
        <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" class="add_remove_row" />
```

Here I gave an class="datepicker" to the *when* named input box. But the next rows do not have this property.

If that matters, by click on that input object, I open a datepicker with the help of [this](http://webdesignandsuch.com/add-a-calendar-date-picker-to-a-form-with-jquery/) site. When I click the *when* named input box in the rows I dynamically create, the datepicker does not show hence it does not inherit the class property. It works fine for the first row which is not dynamically created.

How do I add the class to the element?

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I tried adding a class as well

Comment: I don’t see you trying to add a class anywhere in the code shown.

Comment: I tried adding table.rows[1].cells[3].className="datepicker" after the switch but I guess it adds the class to the <td>. How can I reference to and add class to the element in the table cell in the 3 column?

Comment: Of course `cells` addresses a `td` element.

Comment: So? What do I do? Also tried `table.rows[1].cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].className="datepicker";`